# Why does Firefox show: XML Parsing Error: junk after document element?

Tags: xml, nosql, exist-db, flwor, restxq

Error:

[image: error]

yet from the console, desired output:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ curl http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/scripts/notes.xq
<notes>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

<note>
foo
</note>

<note>
bar
</note>

</notes>
<notes>
<note>
foo
</note>
<note>
bar
</note>
<note>
baz
</note>
</notes>nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lynx http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/scripts/notes.xq  --dump
<notes>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

<note>
foo
</note>

<note>
bar
</note>

</notes>
<notes>
<note>
foo
</note>
<note>
bar
</note>
<note>
baz
</note>
</notes>nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

so that's the output I'm looking for, or similar output, from firefox.

[image: eXide]

The `FLWOR`:

```
xquery version "3.0";

for $note in collection('/db/tmp')/notes
return $note
```

which is as simple as I could make it.

what `eXide` returns from the GUI console:

```
<notes>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

<note>
foo
</note>

<note>
bar
</note>

</notes>
2
<notes>
<note>
foo
</note>
<note>
bar
</note>
<note>
baz
</note>
</notes>
```

which is the output I was looking for.

So perhaps this is more an error of configuration from the browser [more than anything else](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64941000/4531180)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two `<notes>…</notes>` tags in this XML file. The XML specification states that you may only have one root element.

To fix this, remove the:

```
</notes>
<notes>
```

in the middle of the document. That will give you six `<note>…</note>` tags inside a single `<notes>…</notes>` root.

The reason that curl works is because it isn’t trying to parse the XML, but just showing the plain text result.

Comment: I didn't know that any and all documents in that collection would be queries.