# How to "stitch together" results into a single XML document with eXist-db?

Tags: xml, syntax, exist-db, flwor, restxq

How do I create a "single" result of one `notes` element as the root node, with multiple child nodes of `note` elements?

Here's the query in `eXide`:

```
xquery version "3.0";
    
for $note in collection('/db/tmp')/note
return <notes>{$note}</notes>
```

where the output is:

```
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ lynx http://localhost:8080/exist/rest/db/scripts/notes.xq --dump
<notes>
    <note>
bar
</note>
</notes>
<notes>
    <note>
foo
</note>
</notes>nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$ 
nicholas@mordor:~/flwor$
```

How can I get a single document, with a single root element of `notes` which Firefox won't [choke](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64950252/4531180) on?

there are two files, `foo.xml` and `bar.xml` in the collection.

Comment: It is really helpful - actually necessary - to add an example of the data you want to query. Sometimes even the collection structure is important. Please keep that in mind for your next question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML must have exactly one root element.
Also without knowing the structure in the data I would assume you want to get all `notes` regardless how deep they are nested. To achieve that use `collection($col)//note`

```
xquery version "3.1";
    
<notes>
{
  for $note in collection('/db/tmp')/note
  return $note
}
</notes>
```

or

```
xquery version "3.1";
    
<documents>
{
  for $doc in collection('/db/tmp')/document()
  return <notes>{$doc/note}</notes>
}
</documents>
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping the `for` and `return` lines with curly braces?

Comment: you need to tell the parser inside literal XML that a XQuery block starts

Comment: These are called "enclosed expressions." See https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#id-enclosed-expr.